# Getting Error "The coordinates of the range are outside of the dimensions of the sheet" when running script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to run a script that clears a range on sheet 1, then copies a range from sheet 2, then pastes that range from sheet 2 into where the cleared range is in sheet 1. This will be a time-driven script that runs daily. Below is the script.

```
function Skai1() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var range = spreadsheet.getRange('A2509:CU26611');
range.clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('All Performance Data 2022 (Skai)'), 
true);
var range = spreadsheet.getRange('A2:CU5612');
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('All Performance Data 2021 (Skai)'), 
true);
spreadsheet.getRange('\'All Performance Data 2022 
(Skai)\'!A2:CU5612').copyTo(spreadsheet.getrange('\'All Performance Data 2021 
(Skai)\'!A2509:CU26611'),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```

Comment: About `Getting Error "The coordinates of the range are outside of the dimensions of the sheet" when running script` of your title, where does the error ocurr in your script?

Comment: range.clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your actual Spreadsheet. So, if this modified script was not useful for your situation, I apologize. At that time, when you provide the sample Spreadsheet, I would like to confirm the issue.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try

```
function Skai1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sh.getRange('A2509:CU26611' + sh.getLastRow());
  ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- In your current script, an error like `"The coordinates of the range are outside of the dimensions of the sheet"` occurs at the line of `range.clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});`.
- You want to remove this error.

#### Modification points:

- About the error at the line of `range.clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});`, in this case, it is considered that your active sheet might not have the range of `A2509:CU26611`.

  - For example, it supposes that there is a sheet that has 5 rows and 5 columns. Under this condition, `sheet.getRange('A1:Z1000').clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true })` can be worked. Because, in this case, the upper left cell of "A1" includes the existing sheet. On the other hand, when `sheet.getRange('A6:Z1000').clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true })` is run, an error like `The coordinates of the range are out of the size of the sheet.` occurs. Because the sheet has no range of `A6:Z1000`.
  - I thought that this might be the reason for your issue.
  - As an additional information, for example, for this sample sheet, when `sheet.getRange('A6:Z1000').clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true })` is used, an error occors. But, when `sheet.getRange('A6:Z1000').clear()` and `sheet.getRange('A6:Z1000').clearContent()` are used, no error occurs. And, the cells of range are created by expanding the sheet. I thought that this might be able to be used.
- About `spreadsheet.getRange('\'All Performance Data 2022 (Skai)\'!A2:CU5612').copyTo(spreadsheet.getrange('\'All Performance Data 2021 (Skai)\'!A2509:CU26611'),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);`, `getrange` of `spreadsheet.getrange` is required to be `getRange`. But, in your script, I thought that `setActiveSheet` might not be required to be used.

**From your showing script, I thought that you wanted to copy the values from `A2:CU5612` of `All Performance Data 2022 (Skai)` sheet to `A2509` of `All Performance Data 2021 (Skai)`.**

If my understanding is correct and when these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function Skai1() {
  var srcSheetName = 'All Performance Data 2022 (Skai)'; // Please set the source sheet name.
  var dstSheetName = 'All Performance Data 2021 (Skai)'; // Please set the destination sheet name.

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var srcSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  var dstSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  var clearRange = dstSheet.getRange('A2509:CU26611');
  try {
    clearRange.clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true });
  } catch (e) {
    clearRange.clearContent(); // or clearRange.clear();
  }
  srcSheet.getRange('A2:CU5612').copyTo(dstSheet.getRange('A2509'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
}
```

- When this script is run, the content of the range of "A2509:CU26611" in the destination sheet is cleared. In this case, when this range "A2509:CU26611" is outside of the sheet, the range is expanded by `clearContent()`. When the destination sheet has the range of "A2509:CU26611", `clearRange.clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true })` is used. And, the values are copied from "A2:CU5612" of the source sheet to "A2509" of the destination sheet.
- In this case, even when `clearContent()` is changed to `clear()`, no error occurs.

#### Note:

- **Please check your source and destination sheet names again.**

#### Reference:

- [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent)